# Python read XML file (near 50mb)

Tags: python

I'm parsing a XML String into CSV string but it's going very slow:

```
INDEX_COLUMN = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Index"
CELL_ELEMENT = "Cell"
DATA_ELEMENT = "Data"

def parse_to_csv_string(xml):
    print('parse_to_csv_string')
    csv = []
    parsed_data = serialize_xml(xml)
    rows = list(parsed_data[1][0])
    header = get_cells_text(rows[0])
    rows.pop(0)
    csv.append(join(",", header))
    for row in rows:
        values = get_cells_text(row)
        csv.append(join(",", values))
    return join("\n", csv)

def serialize_xml(xml):
    return ET.fromstring(xml)

def get_cells_text(row):
    keys = []
    cells = normalize_row_cells(row)
    for elm in cells:
        keys.append(elm[0].text or "")
    while len(keys) < 92:
        keys.append("")
    return keys


def normalize_row_cells(row):
    cells = list(row)
    updated_cells = copy.deepcopy(cells)
    pos = 1
    for elm in cells:
        strIndexAttr = elm.get(INDEX_COLUMN)
        index = int(strIndexAttr) if strIndexAttr else pos
        while index > pos:
            empty_elm = ET.Element(CELL_ELEMENT)
            child = ET.SubElement(empty_elm, DATA_ELEMENT)
            child.text = ""
            updated_cells.insert(pos - 1, empty_elm)
            pos += 1
        pos += 1
    return updated_cells
```

The XML String sometimes miss a few columns  and I need to iterate it to fill missing columns - every row must have 92 columns. That's why I have some helper functions to manipulate XML.

Right now I'm running my function with 4GB as Lambda and still getting timeout :(

Any idea on how to improve performance?

Comment: Are you using built-in `xml` or `lxml`? I'm not sure if you can use `lxml` in your function environment, but if you can, it will improve it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `normalize_row_cells` constructs ElementTree Element instances but `get_cells_text` is only interested in each instance's child's text attribute, so I would consider changing `normalize_row_cells` to just return the text.  Also, it's performing copies and calling `list.insert`: inserting elements into the middle of lists can be expensive, because each element after the insertion point must be moved.

Something like this (untested code) avoids making copies and insertions and returns only the required text, making `get_cells_text` redundant.

```
def normalize_row_cells(row):
    cells = list(row)
    updated_cells = []
    pos = 1
    for _ in range(0, 92):
        elm = cells[pos - 1]
        strIndexAttr = elm.get(INDEX_COLUMN)
        index = int(strIndexAttr) if strIndexAttr else pos
        if index == pos:
            updated_cells.append(elm[0].text)
            pos += 1
        else:
            update_cells.append("")        
    return updated_cells
```

If you can match your cells to their header names then using [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from the standard library might be even better (you need to profile to be sure).

```
import csv
import io


def parse_to_csv_string(xml):
    print('parse_to_csv_string')
    csv = []
    parsed_data = serialize_xml(xml)
    rows = list(parsed_data[1][0])
    header = get_cells_text(rows[0])
    with io.StringIO() as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
        for row in rows:
            row = get_cells_text(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
        f.seek(0)
        data = f.read()
    return data

def get_cells_text(row):
    row_dict = {}
    for cell in row:
        column_name = get_column_name(cell)  # <- can this be done?
        row_dict[column_name] = elm[0].text or ""
    return row_dict
```